# Cypress: How to check deeplink url

Tags: reactjs, cypress

If I click a deep-like this in the browser:

```
const UIContainer = () => { 
   const onClickDeeplink = () => e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      window.location = "myapp_url_scheme://rest_of_address"
   }
   return(<a onClick={onClickDeeplink()}>Url Scheme Test</a>) 
}
```

how to check deep-like URL on cypress.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use cy.location or cy.url() to then make assertions what location is after you click.  (I assume you're doing something like window.location.href = ... though?)

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/location.html